# How to write join query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Question:

1. Given the Employee and AnnualReviews tables, write a query to return all employees who have never had a review sorted by HireDate.
2. Write a query to calculate the difference (in days) between the most and least tenured employee still working for the company
3. Given the employee table above, write a query to calculate the longest period (in days) that the company has gone without a hiring or firing anyone

[image]

Here is my query in question 1, kindly help to correction and kindly help me write query in question 2,3:

```
Select *,
       annualreviews.reviewdate
From employees
Join annualreviews
On employees.ID = annualreviews.ID
Where reviewdate is null;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the sample data as formatted text instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake #1: You are looking for reviews that have no date, while you should be looking for missing reviews. We typically check existence with `[NOT] IN` or `[NOT] EXISTS`, not with joins.

Your mistake #2: You are joining on the wrong ID. A review ID is not an employee ID, so this: `employees.ID = annualreviews.ID` should ring alarm bells.

The simple query you are looking for:

```
select *
from employees
where id not in (select empid from annualreviews)
order by hiredate;
```

Same thing with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from employees e
where not exists (select null from annualreviews r where r.empid = e.id)
order by hiredate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for that.

```
SELECT employees.*,
       annualreviews.reviewdate
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN annualreviews
ON employees.ID = annualreviews.EmpID
WHERE reviewdate IS NULL;
```

Also you made a mistake in your join condition. You compared with `employees` ID with `annualreviews` ID. However, it should be `annualreviews`'s  EmpID

Answer (score 0):

Use this query
It will show you all the employees who had never had a review sorted by HireDate

```
SELECT e.*,r.ReviewDate FROM Employee e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN AnnualReview r ON e.ID =  r.EmpID 
Where r.ReviewDate is null Order By e.HireDate
```